# React Drag & Drop current component context

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

Anyone who has worked with React Drag & Drop, help needed!

In this example (https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/blob/master/examples/01%20Dustbin/Multiple%20Targets/Dustbin.js#L20) on Line 20, there is `props.onDrop(monitor.getItem());` this code where the function `onDrop` passed to component `Dustbin` via `props` is called.

I need to know if there is a way of calling a method defined inside `Dustbin` instead of passing via props.

Eg: `this.onDrop(monitor.getItem());` or `currentComponent.onDrop(monitor.getItem());`

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, the third argument to drop is 'component' (see here: http://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs-drop-target.html), which is the actual component that was dropped into. So you can do something like:

```
const dustbinTarget = {
  drop(props, monitor, component) {
    component.onDrop(monitor.getItem());
  },
};
```

This argument is available for all of the drop target methods except for canDrop, since the instance may not be available at the time it was called.